# CNTK: How to get the Class-Probabilities in the C++-API?

Tags: python, c++, cntk, softmax

I want to get the class-specific probabilities (where the sum of all probabilities equals to 1) from a trained cnn in cntk. In Python this works as expected by applying a softmax-function:

```
import cntk as C
from skimage import io

model_path = "..."
image_path = "..."
image = io.imread(image_path)
model = C.load_model(model_path)
sm_classifier = C.softmax(model)
class_prob = sm_classifier.eval({model.arguments[0]: [image]})
```

Here, class_prob is a 2-dimensional numpy-array which holds values that seem to be the desired class-probabilities.

In C++ I have the following code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> CnnClassifier::evaluateNet(std::vector<float> flattenedImage)
{
    CNTK::FunctionPtr classifier = CNTK::Softmax(m_cnn); // m_cnn is of type CNTK::FunctionPtr

    // Get input variable. The model has only one single input.
    CNTK::Variable inputVar = m_cnn->Arguments()[0];

    // The model has only one output.
    // If the model has more than one output, use modelFunc->Outputs to get the list of output variables.
    CNTK::Variable outputVar = m_cnn->Output();

    CNTK::ValuePtr inputVal = CNTK::Value::CreateBatch(inputVar.Shape(), flattenedImage, m_device);

    std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable, CNTK::ValuePtr> inputDataMap = { { inputVar, inputVal } };
    std::unordered_map<CNTK::Variable, CNTK::ValuePtr> outputDataMap = { { outputVar, nullptr } };

    classifier->Evaluate(inputDataMap, outputDataMap, m_device);

    CNTK::ValuePtr outputVal = outputDataMap[outputVar];
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> outputData;
    outputVal->CopyVariableValueTo(outputVar, outputData);

    return outputData;
}
```

In outputData, there are no values per class which add up to 1. The values it holds can be very high (up to 15 in my examples) and also can benegative. I believe these are "raw" output values from the last fully-connected-layer. How can I apply the softmax-function to them?

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem myself. It worked when I passed the model to the softmax-function BEFORE training and trained the network with the returned model of the softmax.